# Maintain select box submission value on validation fail - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, validation, foreach

I've read many tutorials on this subject and concluded with the below code. The problem is, the Selection box state value is not maintained when my validation fails.

I have two files:

application.php - this file processes the request.

and

form.php - which is where my select code is:

```
 <select name="textfield6" id="textfield6" class="textbox" style="width:80px;">
 <?
 $states = array('AL' => "Alabama",
'AK' => "Alaska",
'AZ' => "Arizona",
'AR' => "Arkansas",
'CA' => "California",
...
'WA' => "Washington",
'WV' => "West Virginia",
'WI' => "Wisconsin",
'WY' => "Wyoming");
foreach ($states as $abr => $full) {
$selected = ($textfield6 == $abr) ? " select=\"selected\"" : "";
echo "<option value=\"$abr\"$selected>$full</option>\n";
}
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the `$selected` variable, it has to be `selected="selected"` instead of `select="selected"`. (plus the escaping backslashes, of course!)